# How to count the number of Chinese, Korean and English words

Tags: python, cpu-word

I have a sentence mixed with Chinese, Korean and English words. I used the `len()` function in Python but it gave me the wrong answer. For example, we have the string

`a = '여보세요，我是Jason. Nice to meet you☺❤'`

The correct word number, excluding punctuations, is 13, but `len(a) = 32`

How to count the number of words correctly?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

You can take a look on [here](http://ginstrom.com/scribbles/2007/10/06/counting-words-characters-and-asian-characters-with-python/). I have removed Chinese punctuation and counted the number of emoji characters.

```
import re
import emoji
IDEOGRAPHIC_SPACE = 0x3000

def is_asian(char):
    """Is the character Asian?"""
    return ord(char) > IDEOGRAPHIC_SPACE

def filter_jchars(c):
    """Filters Asian characters to spaces"""
    if is_asian(c):
        return ' '
    return c

def nonj_len(word):
    u"""Returns number of non-Asian words in {word}
    – 日本語AアジアンB -> 2
    – hello -> 1
    @param word: A word, possibly containing Asian characters
    """
    # Here are the steps:
    # 日spam本eggs
    # -> [' ', 's', 'p', 'a', 'm', ' ', 'e', 'g', 'g', 's']
    # -> ' spam eggs'
    # -> ['spam', 'eggs']
    # The length of which is 2!
    chars = [filter_jchars(c) for c in word]
    return len(''.join(chars).split())

def emoji_count(text):
    return len([i for i in a if i in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI])

def get_wordcount(text):
    """Get the word/character count for text

    @param text: The text of the segment
    """

    characters = len(text)
    chars_no_spaces = sum([not x.isspace() for x in text])
    asian_chars =  sum([is_asian(x) for x in text])
    non_asian_words = nonj_len(text)
    emoji_chars = emoji_count(text)
    words = non_asian_words + asian_chars + emoji_chars

    return dict(characters=characters,
                chars_no_spaces=chars_no_spaces,
                asian_chars=asian_chars,
                non_asian_words=non_asian_words,
                emoji_chars = emoji_chars,
                words=words)

def dict2obj(dictionary):
    """Transform a dictionary into an object"""
    class Obj(object):
        def __init__(self, dictionary):
            self.__dict__.update(dictionary)
    return Obj(dictionary)

def get_wordcount_obj(text):
    """Get the wordcount as an object rather than a dictionary"""
    return dict2obj(get_wordcount(text))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = '여보세요，我是Jason. Nice to meet you☺❤'
    a = re.sub(r'[\.\!\/_,$%^*(+\"\']+|[+——！，。？、~@#￥%……&*（）：；《）《》“”()»〔〕-]+', "", a)
    b = get_wordcount_obj(a)
    print(b.words)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `len` operator in Python, when applied to a string, gives you the number of **characters** in that string, not the number of words.

If you want to know the number of words in a string, you need to identify a mechanism as to how words are defined - for normal English that could, for example be using a space, and you could use `len(a.split(' '))`. For mixed-language strings including unicode characters you'll need to define custom rules, including separating out cases where each character is a word vs. where words are separated by spaces - in your example you'd need to count the English words separately from the Chinese, Korean and emojis.